# ImageIcon within a JLabel within a JFrame simply REFUSES any attempt to redraw

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, bufferedimage, imageicon

This problem is with my Atari 2600 emulator, and this is frustrating me beyond belief.

My code is in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/2jS9NieD

Essentially, I simply cannot get the BufferedImage within the ImageIcon within the JLabel within the JFrame to refresh what is onscreen, and it is fricking ridiculous.

Comment: Code should be pasted here for viewing, not on another website.

Answer (score -1):

Subclass `JPanel` and override the `paint(Graphics)` method to draw the `BufferedImage` onto the `Graphics` object. Add the panel to your frame, can simply call `repaint()` on the panel when you want to redraw it.

Comment: -1, Although the suggestion for custom painting is reasonable, custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method.